# Why my code keep asking missing return statement

Tags: java, return

```
  public double open() {
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {
        status = "Open";
        if (startPrice <= 5) {
            return 0.2;
        } else if (startPrice > 5 && startPrice <= 20) {
            return 0.5;
        } else if (startPrice > 20 && startPrice <= 100) {
            return 1;
        } else if (startPrice > 100 && startPrice <= 250) {
            return 2.5;
        } else if (startPrice > 250) {
            return 5;
        }
    } else if (!status.equals("Pending")) {
        return -1;
    }           
}
```

Can you explain for my why the compiler keep asking missing return statements. And how can i fix it

Comment: java is not smart enough to know that your 2 if statements are exhaustive. You really need to explicitly tell it. As far as java knows, it's possible for the if and else if to be false and then it doesn't know what to do. It has to return a double but you didn't tell it what to do.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know that `status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")` and `!status.equals("Pending")` cover all the possibilities. In fact, I'm only *guessing* that from inspecting the function names.

You need to help it out.

One fix - if this is your intention - is to write

```
 } else /*if (!status.equals("Pending"))*/ {
     return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
public double open() {
   if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {
        status = "Open";
        if (startPrice <= 5) {
            return 0.2;
        } else if (startPrice > 5 && startPrice <= 20) {
            return 0.5;
        } else if (startPrice > 20 && startPrice <= 100) {
            return 1;
        } else if (startPrice > 100 && startPrice <= 250) {
            return 2.5;
        } else if (startPrice > 250) {
            return 5;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: An explanation as to why the compiler complained is probably helpful.

Comment: "Can you explain for my why the compiler keep asking missing return statements."

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining because all your return statements are in `if statements`. Just delete the `else if` and return -1 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

What if neither

1. status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")
2. !status.equals("Pending")

is true?

You need one more return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Java is not smart enough to determine that you're guaranteed to return. You need to explicitly tell it by having an else on your ifs, or having return at the end to catch any flow through.

In this case, your if statements were redundant as well. The cleaned-up and working version would look as follows:

```
public double open() {
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {
        status = "Open";
        if (startPrice <= 5) {
            return 0.2;
        } else if (startPrice <= 20) {
            return 0.5;
        } else if (startPrice <= 100) {
            return 1;
        } else if (startPrice <= 250) {
            return 2.5;
        } else {
            return 5;
        }
    }
    return -1;          
}
```

`else if (startPrice > 5 && startPrice <= 20)` When you got to this line, you already knew that `startPrice > 5`. If it wasn't then it would have entered the previous if block.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because if :

```
status.equals("Pending")
```

returns `true`, you return nothing.

You can use:

```
  if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {
      ....
  } else {
      return -1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the last `if else` to just `else` to provide a fallback solution. You're providing another `if` condition with `if else`, so there is no branch if this condition is false, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with what the return statement is local to. If all of the if statements were false then the method wouldn't return anything because all of the return statements are local to the if statements. The program can't know that the status would otherwise be pending, thus the compiler complains.

```
public double open() {
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Pending")) {
        status = "Open";
        if (startPrice <= 5) {
            return 0.2;
        } else if (startPrice > 5 && startPrice <= 20) {
            return 0.5;
        } else if (startPrice > 20 && startPrice <= 100) {
            return 1;
        } else if (startPrice > 100 && startPrice <= 250) {
            return 2.5;
        } else if (startPrice > 250) {
            return 5;
        }
    return -1; // no need for an else statement since if an one if statement returned true it wouldn't execute the rest of the code
}
```